# Unable to Download a file with size greater than 9MB from tmp folder using php

Tags: php, download, file-get-contents

I have a web application and below is what I'm try to do

- I'm asking the user to upload a pdf file using simple html page. This file gets uploaded to a temp directory in the server. Then I'm trying to read the contents of file using file_get_contents and put that in the database. This method works fine for files less than ~9MB but fails for files above that size.
- print_r($_FILES) is not blank and has all the values populated which implies that the file is getting uploaded.
- I tried to move the file to another folder and then read it from there but the web application doesn't have write permission, so this method failed. I was successful in moving the file to tmp folder with different name but couldn't find the file in the directory.
- I've tried to read through fread and stream_get_contents but these methods return content of size 1.

PHP

```
$file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
$file_data = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
$file_mime = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['type']);
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
```

- Memory size is 32M, post_max_size is 32M, upload_max_file is 500M
  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the column type. If you do this, which I stress is the wrong way, it should be of type `blob`

Comment: Why are so many people storing binary data in a database?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string/file_get_contents? You should be using http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: what's happening? any errors occurs? try enable error reporting by putting error_reporting(E_ALL) in the beginning of the code - this may help detect the prob

Comment: Why are you escaping binary data with `mysql_real_escape_string`? Also, why are you storing files in a database: **data** base, **file** system:  note the difference. It'll be far more efficient for you in the long run if you store your files on the FS and just keep the path to them in the DB.

Comment: It's the way the application has been designed and is currently working. I can't change that so I've to work within the limitations. For the database part, the column type is longBlob. Moreover, there are a couple of 12MB files in the column, so that is not the issue.
It's a production environment so error reporting is not enabled.I had asked for the log files but the IT guy said that there were no errors. Even the page doesn't have any errors. It sort of breaks at the line where I'm trying to get the content from tmp file. Anything echoed before that line gets printed on the page.

Comment: I tried the E_ALL part but the page is blank.

Comment: As already mentioned, the web application doesn't have write permissions in the directory, so move_uploaded_file is not an option for me.

Comment: Is there any setting which prevents a web server from sending files greater than a fixed size? As I can download small files but nothing above 10MB, I guess it to be an issue with some settings. With a local server, I was able to d/n ~40MB file, so this is not an issue with the method itself but something is preventing me to download large sized files.

Comment: "It's a production environment so error reporting is not enabled" Are you serious? In a production environment, it is even more important to have error reporting (not to the user but to you) so you know when something has happened. Try to reproduce locally with files ranging from 8 MB to 10 MB to see where the issue lies and what causes it.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding but error reporting is enabled but I don't have access to it. I've mentioned that IT guy has gone through the logs and didn't sight any errors. He just won't give me the logs. 
"What causes it" - i've been breaking my head over it. Now I just don't even know where to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `php.ini` file and make the `upload_max_filesize = 32MB`. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: @nathan . Upload is not the issue. The upload_max_filesize is set to 100MB. It's the download which is not going through.